# Harmburger is not showing

Tags: wordpress

Hi everyone I have a bit of a problem here. I have my site that's working perfectly on google chrome but on Firefox the hamburger is not working. The problem seem to be with the add-ons because when I open it in safe mode on Firefox it works. Can some help me with this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest disabling all of your add-ons, and then re-enable them one by one to know which one is causing trouble. From then on you can debug more efficient.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better on [the WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This realy has nothing to do with WordPress.